# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list error when run gulp task with frontend-maven-plugin

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, gulp, frontend-maven-plugin

I have this task in gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('sass', async function () {
    log('Compiling Sass --> CSS');

    var sassOptions = {
        outputStyle: 'nested' // nested, expanded, compact, compressed
    };

    return gulp
        .src(config.sass)
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: swallowError}))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe($.sass(sassOptions))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer())
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp + '/css'));
});
```

when I run this task with `gulp sass` command, everything is ok, but with **frontend-maven-plugin** i get this errors:

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.9.1:gulp (gulp build) @ webapp ---
[INFO] Running 'gulp.js build' in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project

[INFO] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/gulpfile.js:70
[INFO] gulp.task('sass', async function () {
[INFO]                   ^^^^^
[INFO] 
[INFO] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[INFO]     at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
[INFO]     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
[INFO]     at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
[INFO]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
[INFO]     at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
[INFO]     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
[INFO]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
[INFO]     at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
[INFO]     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
[INFO]     at execute (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^4.0.0/index.js:36:18)
```

This is build section of pom.xml:

```
<build>    
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                <nodeVersion>v6.14.4</nodeVersion>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>run npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>gulp sass</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>gulp</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>sass</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```